# pyspark in databricks - replace delimiters and string for every element in RDD at one shot

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I feel stupid when trying to do something so simple as the following: I'm working with dataset /databricks-datasets/cs110x/ml-1m/data-001 which includes 3 dat files with info about user, movies and their ratings.

RDD is like this sample of 10 entries:

```
[u'1::F::1::10::48067',
 u'2::M::56::16::70072',
 u'3::M::25::15::55117',
 u'4::M::45::7::02460',
 u'5::M::25::20::55455',
 u'6::F::50::9::55117',
 u'7::M::35::1::06810',
 u'8::M::25::12::11413',
 u'9::M::25::17::61614',
 u'10::F::35::1::95370']
```

I'm trying to replace what seems to be the delimiter '::' and on the other hand, replace M with 1 and F with 0 which are the genders.

```
myRDD.map(lambda x: x.replace('::',',')).map(lambda x: x.replace('M','0')).map(lambda x: x.replace('F','1'))
```

But it doesn't do a thing, I get the same RDD with no changes with no errors. is there kind of debugger to see what's going on under the hood? this simple thing is driving me crazy. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? If I take 1 element of RDD, it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, but you have to remember it is lazy:

```
>>> myRDD = sc.parallelize([u'1::F::1::10::48067',
...  u'2::M::56::16::70072',
...  u'3::M::25::15::55117',
...  u'4::M::45::7::02460',
...  u'5::M::25::20::55455',
...  u'6::F::50::9::55117',
...  u'7::M::35::1::06810',
...  u'8::M::25::12::11413',
...  u'9::M::25::17::61614',
...  u'10::F::35::1::95370'])
...  
>>> transformedRDD = myRDD.map(lambda x: x.replace('::',',')).map(lambda x: x.replace('M','0')).map(lambda x: x.replace('F','1'))
>>> 
>>> for x in transformedRDD.collect():
...     print(x)
...     
1,1,1,10,48067                                                                  
2,0,56,16,70072
3,0,25,15,55117
4,0,45,7,02460
5,0,25,20,55455
6,1,50,9,55117
7,0,35,1,06810
8,0,25,12,11413
9,0,25,17,61614
10,1,35,1,95370
>>>
```

Normally you wouldn't collect but call one of the distributed actions. I strongly recommend getting familiar with [the programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) before you start wrtiting your own programs.

Comment: Thanks so much. You're totally right, I need to review that guide. I pasted your code and it works for me and after that I decided to check the difference between your RDD and mine. Yours is <class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'> and in my case is <class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>. Doing the same in my case doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, I understand. when I run transformation commands, let's say, nothing gets printed out. here is the part you say "lazy". I need to run  a transformation right?

Comment: Another difference here is that `myRDD.map(...)` doesn't change `myRDD` - it returns a new object. In this solution, `transformedRDD` is printed, but if you printed `myRDD` it would not have changed. Maybe this is your issue.